# esapi encodeForJavaScript Newlines Limitation?

Tags: jsp, esapi

We introduced esapi into our Spring JSP project to handle sanitizing data being rendered into HTML and Javascript. One field we use is set by a third-party webservice and we output the result into a Javascript variable:

```
var errReason= '<esapi:encodeForJavaScript>${myOrder.rateErrorMessage}</esapi:encodeForJavaScript>';
```

The problem is that the result from the WebService sometimes has a newline character appended to the end. I would have thought that encodeForJavascript should handle newlines, but instead the above code renders like this:

```
var errReason 'This was an invalid request: missing required parameter
';
```

Is esapi functioning as designed? Are there any alternatives for dealing with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Needs more context.  Where is the webservice getting called, on the JSP itself or is it handled on the backend on the Controller?  Also, how did you extract the value that appears to be getting rendered?

Comment: I don't think you need that context at all... but yeah in this case the webservice is called on the back end. Its saved into the database and loaded into the JSP. I extracted the value by marshalling the Web Service's return to a POJO and writing it to the db from there. But why does any of that matter? 

The bottom line is that I have a Java String object whose final character is a newline, and esapi is not handling that properly. If I haven't explained this situation clearly please let me know and I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: I'm not convinced ESAPI is your problem.  Try this JUnit:  [    `public void testWindowsNewline() {        Encoder instance = ESAPI.encoder();        assertEquals("\\x0D\\x0A", instance.encodeForJavaScript("\r\n"));    }`    ]  <--It should pass.

Comment: Esapi's taglibs just wrap calls to that method, btw.  I suspect the problem is because you're doing the escaping on the jsp in a javascript context when we really should be doing it back at the service layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given information, it cannot be esapi that is causing your problem here.  The following unit test passes:

```
@Test
public void testWindowsNewline() { 
     Encoder instance = ESAPI.encoder(); 
     assertEquals("\\x0D\\x0A", instance.encodeForJavaScript("\r\n")); 
}
```

FWIW, the [taglibs are just wrappers around the esapi encoder class.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/tags/EncodeForJavaScriptTag.java?av=f)

It appears that you're using the taglibs embedded within javascript strings, which is something that if I saw on a code review on my team I would mark as a defect, and here's why:

There are multiple steps a JSP compiler goes through when it is rendering a page.  You have HTML rendering, data binding,  and JSTL binding just to name a few.  Since this ordering is implementation specific, you want to try and stay away from mixing code like you have here.

I suspect that the JSP compiler is interpreting the `"\r\n"` as HTML whitespace before it makes the call to `<esapi:encodeForJavaScript></esapi:encodeForJavaScript>`.

Here's a couple of things I've done in the past.  I tend to prefer escaping at the Controller/Service layer. This example assumes Spring MVC, and is taking huge liberties.

```
@Controller
public class FooController {
     //This should actually be done in a service class, but this is for demo
     private Encoder = ESAPI.encoder();

     @Autowired
     private DataService dataService;

     //logic for handling request

     public String returnStringEscapedForJavascriptContext(){
          OrderBean myOrder = dataService.getMyOrder(); 
          String unescaped = myOrder.getRateErrorMessage();
          String escapedAsJavascriptData = encoder.encodeForJavaScript(unescaped);
          return escapedAsJavascriptData ;
     }
}
```

The same basic logic would apply if you're converting `myOrder` into a viewBean, etc.

Another solution would be to wrap safe esapi escaping methods as an abstract class that all your view beans inherited from so that way, if you really HAD to do this work in the JSP, you could have something like this:

```
public abstract class SecureBean {
     private Encoder encoder = ESAPI.encoder();
     public String escapeForJavaScript(String input){
          return encoder.escapeForJavaScript(input);
     }
}
```

Then inherit:

```
public class OrderBean extends SecureBean {
     String rateErrorMessage;  //with getters/setters assumed
}
```

Now in your jsp:

```
var errReason= '${myOrder.escapeForJavaScript(myOrder.rateErrorMessage())}';
```

Some of this is a little verbose, but the goal here is to not try and step on the JSP's rendering order.  You might also consider writing an adapter interface for encoding/decoding so you can swap out Encoder implementations--esapi has lost OWASP flagship status and hasn't had a major revision in ~1.5yrs.

Comment: Very informative. I've been busy on another implementation so I have not been able to come back to this but I think you are right. I'll escape this value in the Controller and pass it into the view. Thanks for your insight and hard work.